# Setting circle radiuses from GeoJSON in OpenLayers style and style function

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to set the radius of points coming from a GeoJSON in OpenLayers. I was successful integrating the style in the style function like in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210728/styling-circle-with-radius-depending-on-geojson-property-in-openlayers-3). However, for performance reason, I now put the style outside the function to avoid repeating the style creation for each feature. The problem now is that I don't understand how to set the `radius` in the style with the value retrieved from the style function. I understood there is a `style.setImage()` function but I don't find examples how to use it for circles. Any hint on the link I'm missing here?

```
let style = new Style({
  image: new Circle({
    radius: r * (r / 2),
    fill: new Fill({color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'}),
    stroke: new Stroke({color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)', width: 0.1})
  }),
  text: new Text({
    font: '12px sans-serif',
    fill: new Fill({color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'}),
    stroke: new Stroke({color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)', width: 3}),
  })
})

let styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  let r = feature.get('radius')
  r = Math.round(r * 10) / 10
  style.getText().setText(r.toString());
  //style.setImage(???????);
  return style
}
```

Comment: Method to change style image radius is `style.getImage().setRadius(r)`, but since you have one style for all features, radius will change for all features that use that style.

Comment: @TomazicM As long as the style is only used in a style function setting the radius will not affect other features any more than setting the text will.

Comment: @Mike Your are of course right, since style depends on feature property, not some global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

- using `style.getImage().setRadius(10);`
- cache values to create style to not instantiate one style per feature but reuse it like in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml-earthquakes.html. This proposition suppose you will not have too many radius otherwise you may cache too many objects and mutating the radius like in first case should be better.

Comment: Since style is depending also on feature text, cache is probably out of question here.